# How to size compute/gpu/storage/network for generative AI or LLM?

Tags: model, artificial-intelligence, large-language-model

I would like to provision compute (servers), gpus (say 2 A100 80GB or H100), storage and network (may be 100GbE) to run OpenApaca 7B (https://huggingface.co/openlm-research/open_llama_7b) model.

How do I go about sizing this? AWS/GCP cluster sizing is okay too.